# Можно ли собирать на сервере ошибки, которые привели к крашу приложения у пользователей?

Tags: android

Какие актуальные способы существуют это реализовать?
Поверните в нужную сторону, объясните нюансы если они есть.
Какую библиотеку выбрать, чтоб не ошибиться? Есть лучшие или общепризнанные и популярные варианты?

Comment: Погуглите по сочетанию crashhandler android . Есть разные реализации выбирайте которая больше нравится.

Comment: очень много библиотек существует. Вот одна из нах: http://www.acra.ch/